# Neo4j - Counting rows with where condition

Tags: neo4j, count, cypher, relationship, rows

I'm trying to count the amount of rows that Neo4j will return but the count (or the query) is very slow.

Version 1 (70 sec):

```
MATCH (person:Person)-[:HAS_ORDER]->(order:Order)
WHERE order.timestamp >= 1632434400 AND size((order)<-[:HAS_ORDER]-(:OrderLine)-[:HAS_PRODUCT]->(:Product)) <= 20
WITH order
MATCH (order)<-[:HAS_ORDER]-(:OrderLine)-[:HAS_PRODUCT]->(product:Product)
RETURN COUNT(product);
```

Version 2 (68 sec.):

```
MATCH (person:Person)-[:HAS_ORDER]->(order:Order)
WITH size((order)<-[:HAS_ORDER]-(:OrderLine)-[:HAS_PRODUCT]->(:Product)) AS amount
WHERE order.timestamp >= 1632434400 AND amount <= 20
RETURN SUM(amount)
```

Using Neo4j 4.4 community with about 800000 orders and about 17000000 order lines.

Is there a more efficient way to count the rows?

These are the indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_order_torder_id FOR (n:Order) ON (n.order_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_order_timestamp FOR (n:Order) ON (n.timestamp);
CREATE INDEX idx_person_person_id FOR (n:Person) ON (n.person_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_product_product_id FOR (n:Product) ON (n.product_id);
```

The amount of rows are equal to 4269011.

The EXPLAIN plan:
[image]

Comment: Do you have any indexes ? Can you share what Neo4j reruns after :schema ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because every order line has one product, i can skip the counting of the relation order lines to products:

```
MATCH (order:Order) 
WHERE order.timestamp >= 1632434400 
WITH order 
MATCH (order)<-[:HAS_ORDER]-(orderLine:OrderLine) 
WITH COUNT(orderLine) as productCount 
WHERE productCount <= 20 
RETURN SUM(productCount);
```

This query took 0m17.342s

But i managed to snoop some seconds with the following query:

```
MATCH (order:Order) 
WHERE order.timestamp >= 1632434400
WITH order, size((order)<-[:HAS_ORDER]-(:OrderLine)) AS amount 
WHERE amount <= 20 
RETURN SUM(amount);
```

This query took 0m15.675s

Answer (score 0):

Please try below, hope it will give faster results

```
MATCH (person:Person)-[:HAS_ORDER]->(order:Order)
WHERE order.timestamp >= 1632434400 
WITH order.order_id AS orderid
MATCH (o:Order { order_id: orderid })<-[:HAS_ORDER]-(:OrderLine)-[:HAS_PRODUCT]->(product:Product)
WITH COUNT(product) as productCount
WHERE productCount <= 20
RETURN productCount;
```